# .htaccess - block access to all hidden folders except specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, security, webserver, hidden-files

We have a .htaccess (which is based on the HTML5Boilerpate .htaccess) which contains a section which throws a 404 error for hidden folders.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>
```

I would now like to allow access to a specific hidden folder. Is this the best way to accomplish this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.hidden-folder-to-allow-access-to
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>
```

From what I can tell, the above `RewriteCond` seems to work, allowing access to the folder `.hidden-folder-to-allow-access-to`.  Have I missed anything?